# Using jQuery .remove() to take <li> elements out of an <ol> but the DOM still thinks that the <li> elements are there?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that removes `li` elements from an `ol` when you click on an icon. When the `ol` is totally emptied, I would like to replace the `li` with a bit off filler material so that the user can still drag and drop new `li` elements into the list. (It's kind of a shopping cart setup.)

The problem that I'm running into is that when I use jQuery `.remove()` the `li` is removed from the DOM BUT jQuery doesn't it as being gone. So, for example, calling `.has(".li")` returns true even when all the li's are gone, and calling `childNodes.length` returns the total number of `li` that have ever existed in the `ol`.  Code follows:

```
 function onClick(element)
        var parent = $(element).parent().attr('id');
        $(element).remove();
        var container = document.getElementById(parent);
        console.log(container.childNodes.length); //always logs the total number that have ever existed

        if(container.childNodes.length < 1){
            parent.append("<li class='placeholder'>Drag and Drop Components Here</li>");
```

I'm pretty sure that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559509/jquery-removing-elements-from-dom-put-still-reporting-as-present) isn't the problem because I've been careful to grab the parent container only after the element was removed from the DOM.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The requested `ul` and `li` structure:

```
<h4>Components</h4>
     <ol id="components" class="droppable">
         <li class="placeholder">Drag and Drop Components Here</li>
     </ol>
```

Users drag and drop the following code into the list, which is retrieved via `$.get` from some php scripts.

```
     <li id="$id"><table style="color:white"><tr><td>$this->longname</td>
     <td><a href="#$id" onclick="destrComp(this);" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close">Delete image</a></div></td></tr></table></li>
```

The click handler is the code above.

Comment: can you share the initial markup of the `ul` and the click handler for the remove

Comment: Additional information posted.  I'm not sure what you mean "resetting" per the link I posted.  As I said in the post, because I called the container after the /li/ was removed, the cashing issue in that post shouldn't be a problem. Maybe I either misunderstand that post or your comment.

Comment: `childNodes` contains all nodes (including `textNode` and `comments`). So if you check its `length` then you don't know if these are the remaining `textNodes` containing spaces/newlines that could have been between the `li` elements. A `childNodes.length > 0` does not men that there are _tag elements_ inside of that element.

Comment: I think you should use `$('ol').children('li').length`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have misplaced the function name `onClick` instead of `destrComp`, there are multiple problems.

To the click handler you are passing the clicked anchor element not the `li` element as you as assuming, so when you say `$(element).parent()` or `$(element).remove()` it is not dealing with the elements you think it is dealing.

Try

```
function destrComp(element) {
    var $parent = $(element).closest('ul');
    $(element).closest('li').remove();

    if ($parent.children().length < 1) {
        $parent.append("<li class='placeholder'>Drag and Drop Components Here</li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you seem to be removing the "a" tag, but not the parent.

```
$(element).remove(); //This removes the a tag
$(element).parents('li').remove(); //This removes the parent li element
```